# Can you restore a MarkLogic backup to a new database?

Tags: marklogic

We want to take a backup of a MarkLogic database from last Wednesday and restore it to a new database name on the same server. We are running MarkLogic 5.0-3.1.

Comment: Welcome. Do you know how to start? What have you tried?

Comment: yes, I believe you just have to change the folder name in the backup that represents the forest names of the new forests

Answer (score 1):

If you restore at database-level, it will look at the original forest names, and restore to the original forests. You can trick this by renaming the folders, but you can also restore at forest level. Create a new replica forest for each original database forest, and load the data of the master forest by selecting the appropriate directory under the Forests directory within the database backup directory.

You could also look into Flexible Replication, but that feature might not exist yet in 5.0..

HTH!